# $xy'' + y' = 0$, Why is this in Euler-Cauchy form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having difficulty figuring out why $xy''(x) + y'(x) = 0$ is in Euler-Cauchy form. Can anyone explain this to me?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed to multiply through by x to get x^(2)y" + xy' = 0?

Comment: Whether multiplication like that is "allowed" depends on the context. However, if someone told you that this equation is a Cauchy-Euler equation, then they must have had multiplication by $x$ in mind, so for that person's context the multiplication is allowed.

Comment: As the equation is an ODE only for $x\ne0$, multiplication with $x$ is an equivalent transformation. Alternatively set $u=y'$ so that then directly $xu'+u=0$ is in Euler-Cauchy form.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's explanations and help =] I am working through a DE textbook and came across this problem in the Euler-Cauchy form section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The differential equation $$a_nx^ny^{(n)} + a_{n−1}x^{n−1}y^{(n−1)} +\cdots + a_0y = 0\tag1$$
> is called the **Cauchy-Euler differential equation** of order $n$. The symbols $~a_i,~~ i = 0, \cdots , n~$ are constants and $~a_n\ne 0~.$

Now let us come to your differential equation,$$xy''(x) + y'(x) = 0\tag2$$Multiplying both side by $~x~,$ we have $$x^2y''(x) + xy'(x) = 0\tag3$$ Clearly here $~n=2~$ and $~a_2=1\left(\ne0\right),~a_1=1,~a_0=0~$ are constants.
Hence the differential equation $(3)$ is same as that of equation $(1)$ and it comes from of equation $(2)$. 
Therefore the given differential equation $(2)$, is Cauchy-Euler differential equation of order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply $$\left(x y'(x)\right)'=0$$
so $$xy'(x)=c_1$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{c_1}{x}$$
$$y(x)=c_1\log x +c_2$$